# Не могу понять почему не выполняется условие в цикле

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы, woocommerce, условия

Есть магазин wordpress+woocommerce с товарами. Хочу для определенных категорий товара выводить контент в зависимости от условия `if($category_name==$itemcat) {...}` в коде ниже, но не могу понять почему оно не выполняется:

```
$itemcat = woocommerce_page_title();
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$empty        = 0;
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
   $category_name = $cat->name;
    if($category_name==$itemcat) {...}
}
```

Проверяю вывод через `echo` - и `$category_name` и `$itemcat` выводит правильно и есть среди категорий та, на странице которой нахожусь

Comment: в цикле$category_name,  $itemcat var_dumpом проверяли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$itemcat = woocommerce_page_title(false);
```

Если не изменяет память, по умолчанию эта функция не возвращает, а выводит название

Comment: да, все супер - отлично!